# Как сохранять excel на сервер? java

Tags: java, spring, servlet

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с проблемой в памяти. Сейчас у меня существует метод, который совершает поиск по определённым параметрам и записывает результат в excel. Проблема памяти заключается в том, что первый раз вызывается метод поиска и он собирает 5 гигов информации(условно), а потом записывает их в workbook (итого получается 200 мб + 200 мб). Это очень большая нагрузка. Поэтому хочется сделать так, что бы файл сохранялся сразу на сервер.

```
    //Тут происходит экспорт
    public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

```
    //Контроллер для моего метода
    @Operation(operationId = "Поиск с выводом в Excel")
    @PostMapping("/search-excel")
    public void searchInExcel(@RequestBody SearchExcelSmartCardDto searchExcelSmartCardDto,
                              HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        service.outExcel(searchExcelSmartCardDto, response);
```

Comment: не пишите в Excel, такой объем информации ни один пользователь не осилит (а Excel - это именно пользовательское приложение). Используйте для записи информации серверную СУБД

Comment: 5 гигов - это для примера. Фактически там гораздо меньше памяти, конечно. Но в любом случае, необходимость писать сразу на диск это не отменяет.